# Why japanese file names throwing exception with php Aws sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm uploading files from remote using Aws S3 sdk, but when uploading files with Japanese names sdk throwing exception and stops working..

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Service\Exception\CommandTransferException' with message 'Errors during multi transfer
(Aws\S3\Exception\InvalidURIException) .\Aws\Common\Exception\NamespaceExceptionFactory.php line 91
```

I can't find the fix, so please any help would be appreciated..

Comment: I would raise this directly with AWS through a support case rather than her at StackOverflow as it may simply be a bug in the Amazon PHP SDK.

Comment: @jarmod, i checked some workaround with the file names, but didn't work yet. I'm going to raise a support ticket, and thanks for your reply:)